# Finding the intersection of two lines, in polar coordinates

Tags: trigonometry

The sticking point is figuring out the substitutions for a ratio of cosines of differences.

I have a pair of lines in polar coords:

> $$r = \frac{s_1}{\cos(\theta - \alpha_1)} \qquad r = \frac{s_2}{\cos(\theta - \alpha_2)}$$

where

> $$\begin{align}
> \alpha_1 &= 6^\circ \\
> s_1 &= 0.9945218953682733 \\
> \alpha_2 &= 74^\circ \\
> s_2 &= 0.27563735581699916
> \end{align}$$

I then need to do trigonometric substitution to solve for $\theta$.

> $$\begin{align}
> \frac{s_1}{\cos(\theta - \alpha_1)} &= \frac{s_2}{\cos(\theta - \alpha_2)} \\[4pt]
> \frac{s_1}{s_2} &= \frac{\cos(\theta - \alpha_1)}{\cos(\theta - \alpha_2)} 
> \end{align}$$

I am stumped after that point.

Comment: The equation of a line in polar coordinates is $y=mx + b \Rightarrow r=\frac{b}{\sin\theta - m\cos\theta}$.

Comment: I converted your computer notation to something more mathematical. `s1_val` is now $s_1$, and `s1_ang` is now $\alpha_1$, etc.

Comment: @ChristopherMarley: $r=s/\cos(\theta-\phi)$ is equivalent to the "normal form" $x \cos\phi + y \sin \phi = s$, where $\phi$ is the direction angle of the line's normal, and $s$ is the distance (in that direction) from the origin.

Comment: @RSchumacher Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$s^1_{val} \cos(\theta - s^2_{ang}) =s^2_{val}  \cos(\theta - s^1_{ang})$$

$$s^1_{val} \cos \theta\sin (s^2_{ang})+s^1_{val} \sin \theta\cos (s^2_{ang})=s^2_{val} \cos \theta\sin (s^1_{ang})+s^2_{val} \sin \theta\cos (s^1_{ang})$$

$$s^1_{val} \cos \theta\sin (s^2_{ang})-s^2_{val} \cos \theta\sin (s^1_{ang}) =s^2_{val} \sin \theta\cos (s^1_{ang})-s^1_{val} \sin \theta\cos (s^2_{ang})$$

$$\cos \theta \,[s^1_{val} \sin (s^2_{ang})-s^2_{val} \sin (s^1_{ang})] =\sin \theta [s^2_{val} \cos (s^1_{ang})-s^1_{val} \cos (s^2_{ang})]$$

Comment: I thought
$$s^1_{val} \cos( \theta\ - s^2_{ang}) = s^1_{val} \cos \theta\cos (s^2_{ang}) +  s^1_{val} \sin \theta\sin (s^2_{ang}) $$
Am I missing a step?

Comment: @blue:
Indeed, the larger problem here is to find the intersection of the lines perpendicular to those vectors from the origin, which are the data points.

Comment: If the overall question "substitutions for a ratio of cosines of differences" is not interesting I can delete the post

Comment: @RSchumacher The way to obtain the result requires substitutions for a ratio of cosines of differences, but , even I didn't check it in detail,the result you obtain is a bit strange.

Comment: In this
[plot example](http://rjs.org/temp/figure_3.png)
the circles describe devices' behavior, the markers are maxima, and the intersection of tangents is the vector of the common forcing.
It could probably be refactored, or done Cartesian, but I wanted to keep it polar, if possible.

Comment: I obviously don't post here much at all, and so wondered what the downvotes are thinking.

Comment: @RSchumacher Then it seems to be correct! Well done. Downvotes are probably motivated by the poor presentation of the first version, take a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Following @gimusi: hint
$$s^1_{val} \cos \theta\cos (s^2_{ang})+s^1_{val} \sin \theta\sin (s^2_{ang})=s^2_{val} \sin \theta\cos (s^1_{ang})+s^2_{val} \sin \theta\sin (s^1_{ang})$$
$$s^1_{val} \cos \theta\cos (s^2_{ang})-s^2_{val} \cos \theta\cos (s^1_{ang})=s^2_{val} \sin \theta\sin (s^1_{ang})-s^1_{val} \sin \theta\sin (s^2_{ang})$$
$$ \cos \theta[s^1_{val}\cos (s^2_{ang})-s^2_{val}\cos (s^1_{ang})]= \sin \theta[s^2_{val} \sin (s^1_{ang})-s^1_{val} \sin (s^2_{ang})]$$

$$ \sin \theta/ \cos \theta=[s^1_{val}\cos (s^2_{ang})-s^2_{val}\cos (s^1_{ang})]/[s^2_{val} \sin (s^1_{ang})-s^1_{val} \sin (s^2_{ang})]$$
$$ \tan \theta=[s^1_{val}\cos (s^2_{ang})-s^2_{val}\cos (s^1_{ang})]/[s^2_{val} \sin (s^1_{ang})-s^1_{val} \sin (s^2_{ang})]$$
$$ \theta=\arctan[[s^1_{val}\cos (s^2_{ang})-s^2_{val}\cos (s^1_{ang})]/[s^2_{val} \sin (s^1_{ang})-s^1_{val} \sin (s^2_{ang})]]$$

then plug into $$r = \frac{s_1}{\cos(\theta - \alpha_1)}$$

which I verified with numpy for my problem!
The numerical answer in this case is $$(\theta=0, r=1.)$$